# Sorting using comparator on string with numbers and special character

Tags: java, comparator

I am facing issue in sorting string with numbers using Comparator where my data is like: 
{7.5 mg/5 ml, 5 mg, 5 mg/5 ml, 10 mg, 5 mg/15 ml, 5 mg/5 ml, sample, section}

I tried the below code

```
Collections.sort(List<Record> records, new Comparator<Record>(){
    @Override
     public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
}
```

Am getting the following output when I sort in ascending order
{10 mg, 5 mg, 5 mg/5 ml, 5 mg/15 ml, 5 mg/5 ml, 7.5 mg/5 ml, sample, section}

In the above output the denominator is not sorted properly for 5 mg series and also the sorting is done as like string sort where 10 mg is getting displayed before 5 mg which is wrong. The required output is:

{5 mg, 5 mg/5 ml, 5 mg/5 ml, 5 mg/15 ml, 7.5 mg/5 ml, 10 mg, sample, section}

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: No, we can't - we dont do your work for you. You start by writing your own code; and then when you have specific problems, you write a question with your code and all the details required to help you. Simply see the [help] to understand how this community works; and how/what to ask.

Comment: I  think if you want to have output in the order you mentioned you should use lexicographical order in comparator.

Comment: Please provide us the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort the strings as if they didn't have the accents, you could use the following:

```
Collections.sort(strs, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        o1 = Normalizer.normalize(o1, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        o2 = Normalizer.normalize(o2, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

For more sophisticated use cases you will want to read up on `java.text.Collator`. 
Here's an example:

```
Collections.sort(strs, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Collator usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
        return usCollator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

**Custom ordering:**

final String ORDER= "qazwsxedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp";

Arrays.sort(str, new Comparator() {

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
   return ORDER.indexOf(o1) -  ORDER.indexOf(o2) ;
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your response Jay.  But using Normalizer I get the output like {10 mg, 5 mg, 5 mg/5 ml, 5 mg/15 ml, 5 mg/5 ml, 7.5 mg/5 ml, sample, section}.  Instead 10 mg should be displayed after 7.5 mg/5 ml. Also the denominator part (i.e) after "/" is not displayed in order.